# Cannot install properly MikTeX on Ubuntu

Tags: luatex, miktex, compiling, ubuntu

Recently, MikTeX released a version for ubuntu-like systems, so I thought to give a try. I followed the official [instructions](https://miktex.org/download)  and everything worked perfect.

However, when I tried to compile my document with `LuaLaTeX` engine I got the following error:

> This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400)   restricted system
>   commands enabled. I can't find the format file `lualatex.fmt'!

My question is whether this is a `miktex` problem or if I have to further setup my system

Comment: Maybe you have to install some extra from MikTeX.

Comment: Maybe you can, as under Windows, create/update the format using something like `mo_admin` (for Windows, this is a graphic interface to refresh the FNDB, declare new TeX roots or update the formats.

Comment: @Sigur miktex does not mention that extra fonts installation is necessary

Comment: @Bernard unfortunately, i don't know how to do it in `ubuntu`, since i cannot find a tutorial/guideline at the official site

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone who wants to give a try to MikTeX**

Following **Bernard's** recommendation I managed to overcome compiling problems by updating `FNDB`. In order to do so, I used the following command:

```
sudo initexmf --admin --update-fndb
```

(you can skip `sudo`, if you remove the `admin` option). Alternative, I believe that the command `sudo mpm --admin --update-db` may also work (unfortunately, `MikTeX Package Manager (mpm) does now work for me).

You can find more details at   [MikTeX's page on Git Hub](https://miktex.org/howto/build-unx).

Comment: I hope it asks for authentication since this is installing under `/usr/local`.

Comment: since you add  `--admin` option, your system mentions that you need to execute the command as a superuser (i.e `sudo`).

Comment: How does the on-the-fly installation work, then? It asks for authentication before proceeding?

Comment: when you install `miktex` you automatically accept on-the-fly option. so, you do not need to enable it manually. however, you can do it with the following command `sudo initexmf --admin --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1`. please have a look at the link on my answer for further details

Comment: That strikes me as quite dodgy. I'm not sure anything should be able to modify system software in that way without getting explicit permission. It means something is getting run with privileges somehow ....

Answer (score 0):

All the propositions read here failed.
I then just uninstalled completely MikTex with Synaptic and the error disappeared.
I must say I had texLive installed and it took the relay as stated by

> This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238).

instead of the MikTex 1.0.4 version.